# One way communication with local desktop app from a trusted intranet web application

Tags: wpf, web-applications, chromium, windows-11, intranet

### I have

1. Intranet website, that is added to trusted websites on clients' windows PCs
2. Windows desktop app running on the clients' PCs

### I need

to click on a button in the web app and invoke parametrized function in the Windows desktop app.

How to connect the two apps for one way communication? It's similar to how browser launches a Teams or Zoom meeting via URL, isn't it?

If it's any help, I can make the web app installable as PWA.